# Run a command that is from a plugin in a function

Tags: neovim, plugin

There is a file browser plugin called [fern](https://github.com/lambdalisue/fern.vim) and I would like to open a split with the fern file system explorer open. This is what I have so far:

```
function File_tree()
    execute 'vert sb'
    execute 'Fern .' " <-- Error here
    execute 'vertical resize 35'
    execute 'wincmd l'
endfunction

function Terminal_window()
    execute 'bel split term://fish'
    execute 'resize 12'
    execute 'wincmd k'
endfunction

function Workspace()
    execute 'call Terminal_window()'
    execute 'call File_tree()'
endfunction

call Workspace()
```

I suspect it's because `Fern .` isn't a valid nvim command unlike `vert sb`, etc. And that command is from the fern plugin mentioned above. So is there a way for me to run a command that hails from a plugin?

However, when I run `:call File_tree()` there is no issue, everything works as expect so what's the issue here?

---

## Update to the functions

```
function File_tree()
    vert sb 
    Fern . 
    vertical resize 35 
    wincmd l

endfunction

function Terminal_window()
    bel split term://fish 
    resize 10 
    wincmd k
endfunction

function Workspace()
    call File_tree()
    call Terminal_window()
endfunction

nnoremap <leader>fw :on<cr>
nnoremap <leader>suw :call Workspace()<cr>

autocmd VimEnter * call Workspace()
```

Comment: I didn't read the post properly after the edit. My bad, i'll just revert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running that code block from inside a vimrc file (or `init.vim` for NeoVim), that will explain why the `:Fern` command will not be available yet, since the code in a vimrc will run before plug-in initialization code is executed and custom plug-in commands are only defined there.

In order to have the call only happen once plug-ins have initialized (at which point `:Fern` will have been defined), use a `VimEnter` event, which triggers only once, at startup, but only after initialization is completed.

In your case:

```
autocmd VimEnter * ++nested call Workspace()
```

**Note:** You need the `++nested` to have the code in your functions trigger any other autocmd's needed, such as the `BufReadCmd` implementing `term://` to open a terminal. See NeoVim's [`:help terminal-start`](http://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html#terminal-start) for an explanation of that exact situation.

---

Unrelated, but note also that you don't need to wrap each command in an `execute` here. You only need `execute` if you need to build the command string from dynamic contents, which is not the case here.

(In some cases, you might need `execute` if you're joining multiple commands with `|`, in to prevent a command that would interpret the `|` literally. See `:help :bar` for details on that. But *that is not the case here either*.)

You could just drop every single one of the `execute` calls in the code from your sample.

In your specific case, the function definition could simply read:

```
function File_tree()
    vert sb
    Fern .  " Comment is fine here.
    vertical resize 35
    wincmd l
endfunction
```

And similarly for the two other functions.

Comment: So for example. I can write `:vert sb | Fern . | vertical resize 20 | wincmd l` in the function and that works the same as using multiple `execute`'s?

Comment: Yes. The more straightforward way is to just write them line-by-line though, nothing wrong with that. Note that `:Fern . | some other command` is only possible if the command was defined with `:command -bar`, but I checked the source code and confirmed that's the case. See `:help :bar` for the commands that will recognize a `|` as their own argument, so they would need an `:execute` to be followed by another command, on the same line, with a `|` as a separator.

Comment: I implemented your suggestion (I also edited the question), this is the [desired](https://ibb.co/c6TJQNx) outcome, but instead [this](https://ibb.co/m89wTnx) happens.

Comment: "Do you mean you get the result where fish doesn't seem to open, or the tree from Fern, when using VimEnter? " Both.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect those changes. And I've tried it, but it still gets the wrong result.

Comment: Do you only get the incorrect result during startup (from the `autocmd VimEnter`)? Does it otherwise work when you use the `<leader>suw` mapping?

Comment: `<leader>suw` works fine, and `autocmd VimEnter` doesn't

Comment: It says `"term://fish" [New DIRECTORY]`, which is actually exactly what I get for `:split term://fish` on Vim, which doesn't recognize that syntax (the `term://` syntax is NeoVim specific, I believe.)... Are you sure you're trying that in NeoVim and not regular Vim? Even though the autocmd name is VimEnter, it's supposed to work in NeoVim...

Comment: I am using all of this in my `init.vim` and I am using nvim because vim isn't installed on my system.

Comment: Ah ok I found the issue, you need a `++nested` in your autocmd. In fact, that's explicitly mentioned in NeoVim's help docs. I updated the answer to reflect that fact. See if that works for you now!

Comment: It works now. Thanks!